# Why is there difference between these two sregex_iterator statements?

Tags: c++, regex

This is the first statement:

```
string s("hello.world");
sregex_iterator  pos(s.cbegin(), s.cend(), regex(R"(\.)"));
sregex_iterator end;
for (; pos != end; ++pos)
    cout << pos->str() << endl;
```

This is the second statement:

```
string s("hello.world");
regex reg(R"(\.)");
sregex_iterator  pos(s.cbegin(), s.cend(), reg);
sregex_iterator end;
for (; pos != end; ++pos)
    cout << pos->str() << endl;
```

The second program can run correctly, but the first aborts at the runtime.
[image]

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/orphan

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit poor little iterator :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line:

```
sregex_iterator  pos(s.cbegin(), s.cend(), regex(R"(\.)"));
```

expression `regex(R"(\.)")` corresponds to a temporary object which is being destroyed immediately after function call. All iterators that "point" into it are being invalidated. An attempt to use this iterator leads to failed debug runtime check and assertion is being thrown.

See:

- [cppreference - `std::regex_iterator::regex_iterator()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_iterator/regex_iterator)

Comment: And the error message says this. The iterator has been orphaned.